# How to track subdomains with Google Analytics while having mod_rewrite redirect to a subdomain?

Tags: google-analytics, url-rewriting, referrer

When users come directly to `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`, I am redirecting them to `shop.domain.com` via this .htaccess rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://shop.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The content served by shop.domain.com has the following tracking code parameters:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456-6']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.domain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

All direct visits that come to `shop.domain.com` as a result of the rewrite from `domain.com` are tracked as referral traffic, showing my own `domain.com` as referral source in Google Amalytics.

I would like to track these visits as direct traffic.

How to change the configuration to track mod_rewritten traffic on my subdomain coming from my own domain as direct traffic?

Comment: Has your question been answered here?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overriding the referrer information, you should add the subdomain to the Referrer Ignore List that Google Analytics stores.

You can do this using the **_addIgnoredRef()** method in the GA API.

Google's description of the the method:

> **_addIgnoredRef()**
>
> Excludes a source as a referring site.
>   Use this option when you want to set
>   certain referring links as direct
>   traffic, rather than as referring
>   sites. For example, your company might
>   own another domain that you want to
>   track as direct traffic so that it
>   does not show up on the "Referring
>   Sites" reports. Requests from excluded
>   referrals are still counted in your
>   overall page view count.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiSearchEngines.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addIgnoredRef

**Note:** the examples given by Google may not be 100% correct. Check out the following link for a detailed discussion and example implementation:

http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2011/01/google_analytics_subdomain_tracking.php

Answer (score 2):

You can override the referrer that Google Analytics is using, read more in the documentation for [_setReferrerOverride](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiCampaignTracking.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setReferrerOverride).

To somehow provide this correct referrer, you need to pass it via the 301 redirect. I can suggest adding a query parameter to your redirected url, and writing a javascript snippet that will extract this information from the document.location.

An example of adding javascript to your GA code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
var _from = unescape(window.location.href.replace(/.*[?&]from=(.*)/,'$1'));
if (_from && _from.length > 0) {
  _gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride',_from]);
}
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

And, an example of using mod_rewrite to transfer the referrer, if a referrer exists:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://shop.domain.com/$1?from=%1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://shop.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You will need to repeat the above for www.domain.com as well.

Comment: disclaimer: even though I tried to test this as best as I can, it may still not work 100%. so I leave the testing up to the users of the suggested above.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Evgeny. Even though this seems to work, I would not like to add URL parameters when performing the redirection. I would prefer a method that would not alter user experience in any way.

Comment: well, you can improve the above be redirecting to a url with a hash (#) instead of a query param. and you can remove hashes using javascript without the page reloading in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The following example describes how to keep the referrer while switching from `http` to `https`.

In your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1?referrer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,QSA,R=301]
```

The Google Analytics call:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-xxx-y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
try {
  var match = /.*[?&]referrer=(.*)/.exec(window.location.href);
  if (match && match.length > 1) {  
      var _from = decodeURIComponent(match[1]);
      if (_from && _from.length > 0) {
          console.log('Override referrer:', _from);
          ga('set', 'referrer', _from);
      }
  }
} catch (err) { ; }
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: There should be no space in the `RewriteRule` flags. ie. `[L, QSA,R=301]` should be `[L,QSA,R=301]` (otherwise, you'll get a 500 error).